# Get help in Eclipse on Java keywords

Tags: java, eclipse, helper

Is there a way to get put the cursor in a Java keyword and get help for that keyword? I know it works for apis, but what about the language itself.

I found a feature request for this at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=197903

Comment: hmm, for a keyword? check, maybe theres an add-ono for eclipse

Comment: The best place for help on java keywords is the java tutorial.  I suggest that you bookmark it for reference purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Not without some plugin (if any even exists).  Maybe just check official documentation (ex. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/_keywords.html as a starting point). There really arent that many keywords, and they are fixed (at least per version, unlike classes, methods, etc.). Wikipedia has a page that also includes a brief summary at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords#List.

Comment: I am currently doing a google search for keywords and it is working, but it is not as integrated as the api help.

Comment: I agree it certainly isnt as convenient. But for the majority of keywords that are most commonly used, once you read what they mean and use them a couple times, you probably will never forget what they mean or have to look them up again :). For example, I have never heard of "strictfp", and have no need to bother looking it up, because I have never encountered it.